# Dropbox. Can I set APP_KEY?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Is it possible to set manually APP_KEY? 
In a regular way I must make record in manifest file like this:

```
...
      <intent-filter>
        <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
        <data android:scheme="db-qwertyuiuy12345" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397107/read-informations-from-application-preferences-instead-from-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: Look, maybe I can not understand something... The question is how to edit line <data android:scheme="db-APP_KEY" /> on-fly (I mean if I want to change app-folder while app is working)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to initiate app key with a Manifest entry. Use the following snippet, as it suggested:

```
AppKeyPair keys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
```

Comment: Look here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android 
on topic "Required changes to AndroidManifest.xml"
The question is how to edit line 
 <data android:scheme="db-APP_KEY" />
on-fly (I mean if I want to change app-folder inside working app)